# function only returning zero or very large numbers

Tags: c, function

Trying to write a program that reads input from a file and uses that to calculate a water bill using a function. Whenever I run the program and print the results of the function, it either prints 0, -0, or a very large number. I know the formulas I used are correct because I put them in a calculator and it worked fine, so the I think the problem is in my function or my function call.

first few lines of the file:

```
g 5000

B 1250

M 50

r 120
```

this is the output when I run my program:

```
Type    Water usage     Cost including tax

g       5000            0.000000

B       1250            -0.000000

Wrong user type.

M       50              0.000000

r       120             377145544395 (this number is much larger, I didn't want to copy the entire thing)
```

and my code:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    double water_billcalculation(char user_type, double water_use);


    int main(void) {
    FILE* water;
    water = fopen("water_usage.txt", "r");

    char user_type;
    double water_use;

    
    printf("Type\tWater usage\tCost including tax\n");

    while (fscanf(water, "%c %d\n\n", &user_type, &water_use) != EOF) {
        printf("%c\t%d\t\t%lf\n", user_type, water_use, water_billcalculation(user_type, water_use));
    }



    return(0);
}

    double water_billcalculation(char user_type, double water_use) {
    
    double tc = 0, x;

    if (user_type == 'G' || user_type == 'g') {
        x = water_use * .035;
        tc = x + (x * .087) + 3.75;

        
    }
    else if (user_type == 'B' || user_type == 'b') {
        x = water_use * .0553;
        tc = x + (x * .087) + 17.25;
        
        
    }
    else if (user_type == 'R' || user_type == 'r') {
        if (water_use <= 400) {
            x = water_use * .04;
            tc = x + (x * .087) + 13.5;
            
        }
        else if (water_use > 400 && water_use <= 700) {
            x = water_use * .062;
            tc = x + (x * .087) + 13.5;
            
        }
        else {
            x = water_use * .12;
            tc = x + (x * .087) + 13.5;
        
        }

    }
    else { 
        printf("Wrong user type.\n");
    }
    return(tc);
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, or use a compiler that provides better ones.  With gcc I get `water.c:18:31: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]` on your scanf line, which seems like a good hint.  Your `printf` has the same issue.

Comment: why do so many people compare `fscanf` result to `EOF`

Answer (score 2):

```
    while (fscanf(water, "%c %d\n\n", &user_type, &water_use) != EOF) {
        printf("%c\t%d\t\t%lf\n", user_type, water_use, water_billcalculation(user_type, water_use));
    }
```

Your format strings are messed up.  The `%d` format specifier corresponds to a variable of type `int` (i.e. it needs an `int` for printf, and a pointer to `int` for scanf).  But the variable `water_use` is of type `double`.  This mismatch causes undefined behavior, which can include incorrect values.  The type `double` should use `%lf`. (Other variants are possible, e.g. `%lg`, but I will not discuss them here.  For `printf` the `l` is optional but for `scanf` it is mandatory, so we might as well use it consistently.).

Also, `fscanf` only returns EOF if an error occurred, or the end of the file was reached.  If the file is mis-formatted and only one (or zero) of the input items are successfully matched, then `fscanf` may return 0 or 1 (number of items matched), in which case your program would go ahead with stale or uninitialized data in `user_type` and `water_use`.  So to be safe, you should only proceed if `fscanf` returns 2.

As M.M. points out, `\n\n` in the `fscanf` format string can be replaced by a single `\n` or any other whitespace, but perhaps as it is, it helps document the file format that's expected.  So I won't change that.

So change this to

```
    while (fscanf(water, "%c %lf\n\n", &user_type, &water_use) == 2) {
        printf("%c\t%lf\t\t%lf\n", user_type, water_use, water_billcalculation(user_type, water_use));
    }
```

A good compiler will warn you about the format string problem.  `gcc -Wall` says:

```
water-orig.c: In function ‘main’:
water-orig.c:18:31: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
   18 |     while (fscanf(water, "%c %d\n\n", &user_type, &water_use) != EOF) {
      |                              ~^                   ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                               |                   |
      |                               int *               double *
      |                              %le
water-orig.c:19:22: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
   19 |         printf("%c\t%d\t\t%lf\n", user_type, water_use, water_billcalculation(user_type, water_use));
      |                     ~^                       ~~~~~~~~~
      |                      |                       |
      |                      int                     double
      |                     %f
```

which would have explained the problem immediately and saved you an hour of writing this post and waiting for an answer.

Comment: The `fscanf` return value should be compared against `2`, and the `\n` are redundant . (Possibly there should be space on the front of the format string instead)

Comment: @M.M: Fixed the return value test, and added a note about `\n\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is messed up, with the wrong type and spurious spaces, and you're failing to check for invalid input.  You should have:

```
while (fscanf(water, " %c%lf", &user_type, &water_use) == 2) {
```

- to read a `double` you want `%lf` not `%d` (your compiler should be giving you a warning about this; if not you want to enable warnings)
- you should compare the result of the scanf to the number of things you expect to be correctly parsed.  This will deal properly with (by exiting the loop) reaching the end of file or having malformed data in the file
- you should not have spurious whitespace in the format.  You want a leading space to ignore any whitespace after the previous entry (any blank lines, for example), and you don't particularly want to deal with whitespace after an entry until you need the next entry.